# Export default variable with BabelJS

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm using Babel for ES2015 module definitions.

I have a file `a.js`:

```
require('babel-core/register')({presets: ['es2015']})
require('./b')
```

Which requires a file `b.js`

```
export default b = () => true
```

Babel compiles this to

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports.default = b = function Main() {
  return true;
};
```

But then throws an error:

```
ReferenceError: b is not defined
  at Object.<anonymous> (b.js:1:16)
```

Comment: Does your compiled output have a use strict directive? (It should.) Can you elaborate on what you mean about running the compiled code directly working? What are you trying to accomplish for local bindings / exports? Do you need a local binding to the thing that you're exporting as the default?

Comment: Is the input you're showing the whole contents of `b.js` or an excerpt?

Comment: Ah you mean, Babel only shows me the error line after the compilation, but not the first line, which should be `"use strict";`? This could be, yes. I just copied the line it showed me and tried it to run with node, which worked, but it probably wouldn't if it was strict mode... Anyway I wanted to use babel to create an anonymous function (nicer syntax, no return etc.) but with a name (babel compiles `a = () =>` to `a = function a() {}`

Comment: [This might be relevant](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/why-is-export-default-var-a-1-invalid-syntax)

Comment: @K I'm not sure what you mean about the line after, but the output should have a use strict directive and you can't just run a portion of the code without the use strict directive and expect it to perform the same. You mean an arrow function, not an anonymous function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from babel adding `strict mode` as you are then referencing an undeclared variable. Changing it to:

```
const b = () => true
export default b;
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, seems to be. So if I want a name for an arrow function, I have to move the `export default` from before to behind the function definition?

Comment: Seems to be the case. Alternatively, you could use `export default () => true` then `import b from "./b"`.

Comment: @K..: `export default b = () => true` is basically the same as `module.exports = (b = () => true)`. Maybe that makes it clearer what's happening. You could also just declare the variable beforehand (`let b;`) but I wouldn't consider this good style.

Comment: Having it be declared is the important part, you could also do `let b; export default b = () => true;`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the whole module and there's not a global `b`, then this is a runtime error, so that could be the first problem:

```js
export default b = () => true
```

Comment: I was mistaken to say it's invalid input -- I've updated the answer to reflect that in your case it's likely a runtime error.